# Update cursor in createjs

Tags: canvas, cursor, createjs

I'm new to canvas. I'm implementing an application using createjs. I have placed an PNG image on the canvas stage. I want to change the cursor style to 'grap' on mosueover and want the cursor style as 'grapping' while dragging the PNG image. I would like to do this on createjs only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it already looks (hence why it's good to give as many details as possible), so I will take it step-by-step;

```
//reference the canvas with:
var canvas = document.getElementById("yourCanvasID");
//create your stage
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
//enable mouse events for the stage
stage.enableMouseOver();
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

I am assuming you have the image loaded already and referenced with a variable, but not added to the page yet. Let's say it's called `image`.
You can create a bitmap image from it with:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
```

and then add it to the stage

```
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

After that you add the event listeners to the newly created createjs bitmap object with:

```
bitmap.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouse);
bitmap.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouse);
bitmap.addEventListener("pressmove", handleMouse);
bitmap.addEventListener("pressup", handleMouse);
```

And then you define what will happen inside the `handleMouse` function:

```
var isMouseDown = false;
function handleMouse(evt)
{
   switch (evt.type){
      case "mouseover":
         //on rolling over the image
         if (!isMouseDown){
             canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
         }
         break;
      case "mousedown":
         //when holding the mouse down;
         canvas.style.cursor = "move";
         isMouseDown = true;
         break;
      case "pressmove":
         //move the image
         bitmap.x = stage.mouseX;
         bitmap.y = stage.mouseY;
         break;
      case "pressup":
         //when releasing the mouse click
         isMouseDown = false;
         canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
   }
}
```

Now, I am not sure if everything is 100% correct since it comes from the top of my head, but it should do the trick with changing the mouse between "hand" and "move" pointers.

Comment: The work you did to detect mouseover and change the cursor is unnecessary. Check out http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_cursor

Comment: Ah, that's a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

The answer @catalin gave you is mostly correct for setup, but adding the cursor is way easier, since EaselJS [supports it natively](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_cursor).

1. Make sure to `enableMouseOver()` on the stage. This ensures that EaselJS checks what is under the mouse. This can be expensive, so it can be prudent to turn off `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` on anything that doesn't need mouse interaction.
2. Add a `cursor` property to anything you want to have a cursor.

That's it!

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasId");
stage.enableMouseOver();

var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("path/to/image.png");
stage.addChild(bmp);
bmp.cursor = "pointer";
```

Cheers.